# refer a module in another module

Tags: javascript, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have created a module 'one_time_popup' and I want to call the module 'home_landing_page' which has my required js 'service.js'
I want to use to function in  service.js which is in home_landing_page module.I want to call the service.js function in one_time_popup module

```
one_time_popup.info
name = onetimepopup
description = Get my details from soap service
package = onetimepopup Services
core = 7.x
version = "7.x-3.0"
files[] = one_time_popup.module
dependencies[] = home_landing_page

home_landing_page.js
name = Site Homepage
description = Provides a homepage for the site for anonymous and authenticated users
core = 7.x
package = Landing pages
php = 5.2.4
project = home_landing_page
scripts[] =restservice.js
scripts[] =service.js

service.js
 function sendRequest() {}
 function sendRequestCall() {}

one_time_popup.module
if (module_exists('home_landing_page')) { 
  want to call service.js
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```html
if (module_exists('module_name')) { 
    module_name_function_name();
  }
```